# Transaction inside` TransactionSynchronizationManager` afterCommit with TaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I have a code using `TransactionSynchronization.afterCommit` through `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(...)` inside a transaction:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization() {
  @Override
  public void afterCommit() {
    Manager.save(param)
  }
});
```

In afterCommit code is called a method with `@Transactional`:

```
public class ManagerImpl implements Manager {
  @Transactional
  public void save(...) { ... }
}
```

I use Spring, Hibernate and EntityManagerFactory, this code runs well when it's running inside Spring MVC, otherwise, when comes a web request but when runs inside a TaskExecutor (`org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`) I get the error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2083.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.flush(Unknown Source)
//called entityManager.flush()
```

I checked the transaction using `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` and it returns true.

Answer (score 4):

When the `#afterCommit()` method is called, Spring may still see that the context is bound to an existing transaction, its just that the transaction has been comitted; hence why you see it may be active.

Per the javadoc for the method [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html#afterCommit--), if you'd like to allow other code to run that requires a transaction, you need to force Spring to generate a new propagated transaction.  So change your `Manager#save` method as follows:

```
public class ManagerImpl implements Manager {
  @Transactional(propagation = PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW) 
  public void save( ... ) {
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked! But what I don't understand is why this works in a Spring MVC Context with just `@Transactional`? I think it should work in TaskExecutor context as well.

Comment: Hmm, I've lost hours today just to find out that `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` is not reliable :/ Thanks for this info.

Answer (score 1):

This works only if the `PlatformTransactionManager` class that is responsible for managing the transaction, is capable of differentiating between the older transaction in the completed state, and the new transaction that is being started in the `TransactionSynchronization`.

`PlatformTransactionManager` classes like the `HibernateTransactionManager` are incapable of enforcing this in all circumstances, due to internal implementation details. This is primarily because `HibernateTransactionManager` ties a Hibernate `Session` with a `Transaction` instance through a `SessionHolder`. `SessionHolder` instances are cached in a threadlocal variable. When a new transaction is started in the same thread, `HibernateTransactionManager` retrieves the `SessionHolder` associated with the thread, to reuse the transaction and Hibernate session.

In normal circumstances, this isnt so much of an issue, since the thread-local cache is cleared on commit or rollback of the transaction. In a `TransactionSynchronization` however, the thread-local values are not yet cleared, and thus prevents a new transaction from being initialized, unless one does it explicitly.

There are many ways to solve this:

1. Use Transation propagation of REQUIRES_NEW. This may be seen as a hack, unless it is specified on a method in a facade. It forces the Spring transaction aspect to start a new transaction, bypassing the issues involving the edge case described above.
2. Perform the transactional work in a new thread. This ensures the thread-local caches dont intefere with starting a new transaction. An `@Async` annotated method can be used to wrap the work.
3. Decouple the transaction sycnhronization and dont perform any work in the tranasction synchronization adapter. Instead, publish an event and process the event asynchronously - the transactional work can be done in the event listener.